# android-how to move image to center of this CustomImageVIew

Tags: android, android-imageview

I needed to able zoom images inside an imageView.

I've searched and used this CustomImageVIew and it works fine.

The only problem is this, it move the image to the top left corner of the screen.

Sorry, I can't post screenshot, consider this, it's in 1/4 of the screen at top left corner.

I want to make the image to come to center of the screen

this is the class:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.graphics.PointF;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class CustomImageVIew extends ImageView implements OnTouchListener {


private Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
private Matrix savedMatrix = new Matrix();

static final int NONE = 0;
static final int DRAG = 1;
static final int ZOOM = 2;

private int mode = NONE;

private PointF mStartPoint = new PointF();
private PointF mMiddlePoint = new PointF();
private Point mBitmapMiddlePoint = new Point();

private float oldDist = 1f;
private float matrixValues[] = {0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f};
private float scale;
private float oldEventX = 0;
private float oldEventY = 0;
private float oldStartPointX = 0;
private float oldStartPointY = 0;
private int mViewWidth = -1;
private int mViewHeight = -1;
private int mBitmapWidth = -1;
private int mBitmapHeight = -1;
private boolean mDraggable = false;


public CustomImageVIew(Context context) {
    this(context, null, 0);
}

public CustomImageVIew(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, 0);
}

public CustomImageVIew(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    this.setOnTouchListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onSizeChanged (int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh){
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    mViewWidth = w;
    mViewHeight = h;
}

public void setBitmap(Bitmap bitmap){
    if(bitmap != null){
        setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        mBitmapWidth = bitmap.getWidth();
        mBitmapHeight = bitmap.getHeight();
        mBitmapMiddlePoint.x = (mViewWidth / 2) - (mBitmapWidth /  2);
        mBitmapMiddlePoint.y = (mViewHeight / 2) - (mBitmapHeight / 2);

        matrix.postTranslate(mBitmapMiddlePoint.x, mBitmapMiddlePoint.y);
        this.setImageMatrix(matrix);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event){
    switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        savedMatrix.set(matrix);
        mStartPoint.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
        mode = DRAG;
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
        oldDist = spacing(event);
        if(oldDist > 10f){
            savedMatrix.set(matrix);
            midPoint(mMiddlePoint, event);
            mode = ZOOM;
        }
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
        mode = NONE;
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        if(mode == DRAG){
            drag(event);
        } else if(mode == ZOOM){
            zoom(event);
        } 
        break;
    }

    return true;


  }



   public void drag(MotionEvent event){
       matrix.getValues(matrixValues);
   float left = matrixValues[2];
   float top = matrixValues[5];
   float bottom = (top + (matrixValues[0] * mBitmapHeight)) - mViewHeight;
   float right = (left + (matrixValues[0] * mBitmapWidth)) -mViewWidth;

   float eventX = event.getX();
   float eventY = event.getY();
   float spacingX = eventX - mStartPoint.x;
   float spacingY = eventY - mStartPoint.y;
   float newPositionLeft = (left  < 0 ? spacingX : spacingX * -1) + left;
   float newPositionRight = (spacingX) + right;
   float newPositionTop = (top  < 0 ? spacingY : spacingY * -1) + top;
   float newPositionBottom = (spacingY) + bottom;
   boolean x = true;
   boolean y = true;

   if(newPositionRight < 0.0f || newPositionLeft > 0.0f){
       if(newPositionRight < 0.0f && newPositionLeft > 0.0f){
           x = false;
       } else{
           eventX = oldEventX;
           mStartPoint.x = oldStartPointX;
       }
   }
   if(newPositionBottom < 0.0f || newPositionTop > 0.0f){
       if(newPositionBottom < 0.0f && newPositionTop > 0.0f){
           y = false;
       } else{
           eventY = oldEventY;
           mStartPoint.y = oldStartPointY;
       }
   }

   if(mDraggable){
       matrix.set(savedMatrix);
       matrix.postTranslate(x? eventX - mStartPoint.x : 0, y? eventY - mStartPoint.y : 0);
       this.setImageMatrix(matrix);
       if(x)oldEventX = eventX;
       if(y)oldEventY = eventY;
       if(x)oldStartPointX = mStartPoint.x;
       if(y)oldStartPointY = mStartPoint.y;
   }



}

   public void zoom(MotionEvent event){
       matrix.getValues(matrixValues);
   float newDist = spacing(event);
   float bitmapWidth = matrixValues[0] * mBitmapWidth;
   float bimtapHeight = matrixValues[0] * mBitmapHeight;
   boolean in = newDist > oldDist;

   if(!in && matrixValues[0] < 1){
       return;
   }
   if(bitmapWidth > mViewWidth || bimtapHeight > mViewHeight){
       mDraggable = true;
   } else{
       mDraggable = false;
   }

   float midX = (mViewWidth / 2);
   float midY = (mViewHeight / 2);

   matrix.set(savedMatrix);
   scale = newDist / oldDist;
   matrix.postScale(scale, scale, bitmapWidth > mViewWidth ? mMiddlePoint.x : midX, bimtapHeight > mViewHeight ? mMiddlePoint.y : midY); 

   this.setImageMatrix(matrix);


   }




/** Determine the space between the first two fingers */
private float spacing(MotionEvent event) {
    float x = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);
    float y = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);

    return (float)Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
}

/** Calculate the mid point of the first two fingers */
private void midPoint(PointF point, MotionEvent event) {
    float x = event.getX(0) + event.getX(1);
    float y = event.getY(0) + event.getY(1);
    point.set(x / 2, y / 2);
}




 }
```

this is layout xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:gravity="center"
android:background="#000" >

<mypackagename.CustomImageVIew
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" 
    android:scaleType="matrix"
     />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you're calling `setBitmap` before the view is visible on screen, while it still has a width and height of zero.

There are a few options for fixing this, but generally speaking you could change the image view so it does the calculation that happens in `setBitmap` either the first time `onSizeChanged` is called with a width and height greater than zero, or the first time `onDraw` is called and both `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` return greater than zero. When `setBitmap` is called and the view already has a width and a height, do the calculation immediately.

Here's a rough (untested) illustration:

```
@Override
public void onSizeChanged (int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh){
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    mViewWidth = w;
    mViewHeight = h;
    if (w > 0 && h > 0 && mBitmapWidth > 0 && mBitmapHeight > 0) {
        centerBitmap();
    }
}

public void setBitmap(Bitmap bitmap){
    if(bitmap != null){
        setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        mBitmapWidth = bitmap.getWidth();
        mBitmapHeight = bitmap.getHeight();

        if (getWidth() > 0 && getHeight() > 0) {
            centerBitmap();
        }

    }
}

private void centerBitmap() {
    mBitmapMiddlePoint.x = (mViewWidth / 2) - (mBitmapWidth /  2);
    mBitmapMiddlePoint.y = (mViewHeight / 2) - (mBitmapHeight / 2);

    matrix.postTranslate(mBitmapMiddlePoint.x, mBitmapMiddlePoint.y);
    this.setImageMatrix(matrix);
}
```

Comment: after spending some time it works , your code is fine , the problem was from java file ,I should've  used img.setBitmap(bitmap); instead of this img.setImageBitmap(bitmap); . anyway thanks you

Answer (score 0):

Take Framelayout instead of Relative layout and try..